# Button action or similar in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Is there a way to do something similar to the attribute NSLinkAttribute but instead of open an url I want trigger an action on iOS?

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"http://www.google.com" range:range];
```

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText and its link button.

Comment: Why not use a button?

Comment: It's an horrible solution, but you can still make an url that call your app with parameters (brrrrr what an idea...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

In UITextViewDelegate, there is a method:

```
textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:
```

If you return NO, you can intercept the click and the longclick of the link.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    [self MAKE_YOUR_ACTION];
    return NO;
}
```

It works only in iOS7. In older versions the only solution I found was the one suggested by @Anc Ainu in the comments of the question.